# overloading universal references in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading Effective modern C++ by Scott Meyers From item 27 overloading universal references.

I am compiling below code in `VC++ 2012`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void logAndAddImpl(T&& name, std::false_type) {
    std::cout << " Reference type " << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void logAndAddImpl(int Idx, std::true_type) {
    std::cout << "int type" << std::endl;

}


template<typename T>
void logAndAdd(T&& name) {
    logAndAddImpl(std::forward<T>(name), std::is_integral<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>());
}


int main() {
    int i = 10;
    logAndAdd(i);

    return 0;
}
```

I am facing compilation error as shown below :

```
error C2664: 'void logAndAddImpl<int&>(T,std::false_type)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::is_integral<int>' to 'std::false_type'
```

Comment: Remove `template <typename T>` from the second overload

Comment: Piotr is correct, or replace with void logAndAddImpl(T Idx, std::true_type) {

Comment: On a side note, I am not a fan of the term 'universal reference'. I think, Scott did community a disservice by introducing this confusing name. There is nothing universal about them, they are still rvalue references. They are no more universal than simple `T&`.